# "enable passive mode in your FTP client" What does it mean, and how I do it

Tags: ftp

I tried to connect to a different machine with FTP.
I continually get

> 500 Unable to service PORT commands
>   ftp: bind: Address already in use

The solution I got was to enable passive mode in my FTP client.
What does it mean, and how do I do it?

Comment: You'll find a lot of existing answers on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=FTP+passive+mode) about passive FTP. We can't explain how to configure an FTP client for passive FTP without knowing its name, but AskUbuntu probably isn't the best forum for that answer anyway--the documentation of any FTP client that's worth using will have an explanation.

Comment: What ftp client do you use? And is this question linked to Ubuntu in any way?

Comment: This [link](http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html) will help you to understand distinction between active and passive modes of FTP.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

If you are using the command-line `ftp` client, invoke it as `pftp` or `ftp -p` instead, which will enable passive mode. If not, find the documentation for your FTP client and search it for "passive mode". [This link](http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html) contains a detailed explanation of passive mode.